# Access 2010 - enter references to form elements as the value of a text field

Tags: forms, reference, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to take a value from a field on a form and use it as a reference to a different field in the same form, and not just literally? I want to be able to manually enter something like [txtFlavor] in one field and have it show the actual flavor, the value of the field named "txtFlavor" in another field, and not just the string "[txtFlavor]". I'm basically trying to store some vba references (terminology?) in a table so I can bring up a string of text with references to values on the form.

I have been asked to create a system that will store letter templates in Access 2010 and allow users to choose a record with personal information and insert that info into a template letter, preferably displaying it on a form immediately in plain text. I already proposed using reports to do this but that was unacceptable to the end users. They really just want a form that combines

a) contact records, one at a time
with
b) letter templates, one at a time

I've been trying to store the template info with it's form references in a table, but I have yet to be able to make references pull data from another text field on the form.

Is it possible and/or sensible to try to store something like the following in a table, or to enter it into a field on a form?

```
[txtFlavor] & " is dull but popular."
```

and then have it show up elsewhere in the form as

```
Vanilla is dull but popular.
```

I sure feel dumb and am sure I've missed something obvious. Everything I do is just repeated literally and not interpreted as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your users to create their templates using 'tags' as placeholders for the database information, in a similar way to how you would design a merge document in Word. So in your example above, the template document would look like:

```
{Flavor} is dull but popular.
```

When it comes time to create the merged result you would need to use the `Replace` function to change these tags to actual data values. So if you had a read-only text box on your form, the control source could be:

```
=Replace([txtTemplate], "{Flavor}", [Flavor])
```

I assume you would have lots of potential tags, so using this approach you would need to nest the `Replace` functions. I have split my nesting across multiple lines to make it a bit more readable:

```
=Replace(
    Replace(
        Replace([txtTemplate], "{EmpName}", [EmpName]), 
        "{EmpAddress}", [EmpAddress]),
    "{EmpPhone}", [EmpPhone])
```

If you had many more database fields/tags this would start to become very unwieldy so I would recommend using some VBA to make life easier, maybe something along the lines of:

```
Dim rsSource As Recordset
Dim strMerge As String
Dim intField As Integer

'Assuming your form has a field called EmpNo (numeric data) that you can use to pull data...
Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("Select EmpName, EmpAddress, EmpPhone From Employees Where EmpNo = " & Me.EmpNo)
strMerge = txtTemplate
For intField = 0 to rsSource.Fields.Count - 1
    strMerge = Replace(strMerge, "{" & rsSource(intField).Name & "}", rsSource(intField))
Next intField

txtMerge = strMerge

rsSource.Close
Set rsSource = Nothing
```

You could put this code in the AfterUpdate event of your txtTemplate text box and it would update the contents of the txtMerge text box. You either need your `tag` names to match your database columns, or else you could alias the columns in the `Select` statement so they match the `tag` names.

Comment: Skippy's answer solved the problem. Now what I would really like to do is to reframe the question so that it is easier to understand, and hopefully catches the eye of someone with a similar problem. I'd be very grateful to anyone who could give me some feedback on this. It's clear to me now that what I was really looking for was a way to enter into a form, or store in a table, the information that would serve as a reference to a field on a form. Skippy's solution works perfectly for what I am trying to do, but it seems that the problem is very hard to describe as it is so self-referential.